# Azure APIm not allowing HTTPS on more than one API

Tags: azure, https, soap, wsdl

We have setup an APIm in Azure with 2 APis. One is a SOAP service that was created from a WSDL. It has a single POST operation which operates just fine using HTTPS. Since we are migrating to cloud and want to keep the migration mostly transparent to clients, it also has a GET operation for exposing the WSDL to clients. This was established using the instructions found here: https://mbraekman.github.io/2020/05/24/Expose-WSDL-through-APIM/ and works just fine using the */soapAction=wsdl* in the GET operation.

However, in the name of not changing things on clients, we need to use the alternative method, which keeps the URL at */myserver/api?wsdl* instead of having to include the */?soapAction=wsdl* parameter.

This results in the following setup:

SOAP API has the following configuration:

- **Display Name:** Submit Service SOAP
- **WebService URL:** https://my-apim.dev.azure.net/SubmitService/Submit.svc
- **URL Scheme:** HTTPS
- **API URL Suffix:** SubmitService/Submit.svc
- **Operations:**

  - **POST** /?soapAction={any}
  - **GET** /?soapAction=wsdl

For the WSDL API:

- **Display Name:** API For WSDLs
- **WebService URL:** https://my-apim.dev.azure.net/
- **URL Scheme:** HTTP(S)
- **API URL Suffix:** None (as they get defined in the operations)
- **Operations:**

  - **GET** /SubmitService/Submit.svc?singleWsdl
  - **GET** /SubmitService/Submit.svc?wsdl

The problem is, that when visiting the HTTPS https://my-apim.azure-api.net/SubmitService/Submit.svc?singleWsdl or ?wsdl, there is a 404 not-found error returned. However, going to the HTTP version, the WSDL is returned as expected.

If I change the URL Scheme to "HTTPS" for the WSDL API, and hit the https:// url, it's 404, if I try http:// still 404. The only thing that works is using a URL Scheme of "HTTP" or "HTTP(S)" and hitting the http:// url. I know this technically works, but the current URL is using https:// and we want to keep it that way.

I suspect there is some kind of collision between the 2 APIs and HTTPs, is there something I'm missing here?

I want to have the 2 APIs, both using HTTPs

EDIT: I did some more experimentation through editing of the WebService URL, including  (as you can see in the SOAP API) including the full URL in the *WebService Url* property as well as changing the URLs/suffixes so that one of them is *https://my-apim.dev.azure.net/SubmitService* and the other is *https://my-apim.dev.azure.net/SubmitService/Submit.svc*

What **does work** is renaming the two like so:

*https://my-apim.dev.azure.net/SubmitService/*

and

*https://my-apim.dev.azure.net/SubmitService2/*

with the respective Suffixes

But this is not ideal, as it is now a separate API/URL for clients, where the current on-prem hosted solution, it is not.